# NullPointerException while getting column names using Hibernate in Struts2 action class

Tags: hibernate, nullpointerexception

I am trying to get all the column names which are generated through hibernate configuration using the following code:

```
ClassMetadata classMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(PersistenceClassName.class);
String[] propertyNames = classMetadata.getPropertyNames();
```

I am getting the following exception:

Root cause:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    PersistenceClass<init>
```

Exception:

```
Unable to instantiate Action
```

I  tried implementing `ModelDriven` interface but still the same exception.

```
@Override // by implementing model driven interface
public Object getModel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return ddObj;
}
```

This is how I tried with  `ModelDriven`:

```
PersistenceClassName PersistenceClassObj= new PersistenceClassName();
List<PersistenceClassName> PersistenceClassList=new ArrayList<PersistenceClassName>();

Object entityName = getModel();
ClassMetadata hibernateMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(entityName.getClass());
```

I am unable to understand how to solve it. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is thrown in the constructor of `PersistenceClass`. If you remove the code caused `NullPointerException` from it then Struts would be able to instantiate an action class via its object factory.

The exception is thrown dynamically if the code is trying to call a method on the variable that is not initialized.

In your code such variable can be `sessionFactory`. Hibernate returns `null` reference if it can't build a session factory.

Comment: If a remove sessionFactory, on what object would I call getClassMetadata() or should I typecast getClassMetadata()  to ClassMetaData?

Comment: You should initialize session factory before you use the variable.